# PHP Session is set but not accessible in different pages

Tags: session, session-variables, php

I am using php session for accessing various values in different pages. Session is set but its not being accessible in different pages.

below is the code which i am using

in validation.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["username"] = $username;
$_SESSION["user_id"]  = $user_id;
```

in profile.php

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION["username"];
$user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
```

but both the variables return null value but when i am using below code in 
validation.php is shows session is set

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
```

This gives proper output in validation.php but its not being accessed at profile.php

i have tried with

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

after

```
session_start();
```

but nothing is happening.

Please help me out this.

Answer (score -1):

The session set in validation.php is accessible in profile.php as you have mentioned session_start(); before accessing.
There is no issue in way of access.
You have to redirect the page after setting session value to make it accessible by other pages.
If you are accessing profile.php through redirection it will print and if through ajax then it will not print.
Once after redirection it will work and print.

Comment: what if i dont do redirect i have done this kind of job before but this time i am not able to understand why its happening.